# Valor formatado com 1 casa decimal no ngModel

Tags: angularjs

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
dadosAnv = { horas_cel: 1950.0 }
```

Acontece que quando vou editar este valor, ele aparece no input apenas `1950`.
Eu gostaria de manter o `.0` do valor, porém não faço ideia de como formatar esse valor através de uma diretiva por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **EDITADO**: Conforme edição do AP, criei uma diretiva que formata o valor
>   conforme a necessidade. Coloquei duas opções, utilizando o `toFixed()`
>   do `JavaScript` ou o `$filter` do `Angular`.

Utilize o filtro [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number).

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.val = 1234.0;
    }
  ]);

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('myDirective', function($filter) {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
        ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
          return $filter('number')(data, 2);
          //return Math.round(data).toFixed(2);
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
  <label>Informe o número:
    <input type="text" ng-model='val' my-directive>
  </label>
  <br>Formatação padrão: <span id='number-default'>{{val | number}}</span>
  <br>Sem casas decimais: <span>{{val | number:0}}</span>
  <br>Com 2 casas decimais: <span>{{val | number:2}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Pedro Camara Jurnior, o filtro number não serve no meu caso pois ele não formata o <input> que é o meu problema. Acho que teria que ser uma diretiva para fazer isso, porém como sou iniciante só sei fazer a formatação no momento da digitação. Um simples toFixed(1) resolveria!

Comment: Entendi agora, da uma olhada na resposta editada,

Comment: É isso mesmo, vlw Pedro!